# Class based component is not working as expected in ReactJs appication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component, react-functional-component, react-class-based-component

I am trying to show the content of my class-based component in part of the functional component but it is not working.
class-based component:

```
class commentForm extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Hello</h1>
                <Button class="btn btn-light"><span className="fa fa-comment-o"></span> Submit 
                comment</Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Functional component:

```
function RenderComments({comments})
{
    if(comments!=null)
    {
        return (
            <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                <h4>Comments</h4>
                <ul className="list-unstyled">
                    {comments.map((comment)=>{
                        return(
                            <li key={comment.id}>
                                <p>{comment.comment}</p>
                        <p>-- {comment.author} , {new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US',{ year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day:'2-digit' }).format(new Date(Date.parse(comment.date)))}</p>
                            </li>
                        );
                    })}
                </ul>                
                <commentForm />
                {commentForm}
            </div>
        )
    }
    else{
        return(
            <div></div>
        );
    }
}
```

.

Here I want to display the content of commentForm from RenderComments. I am not getting any error but code is not displaying the content of commentForm on frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name your component starting with an uppercase letter, `commentForm` should be renamed as `class CommentForm extends Component {}`.

Form the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized):

> User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized When an element type
> starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a built-in component like
> `<div>` or `<span>` and results in a string 'div' or 'span' passed to
> React.createElement. Types that start with a capital letter like  compile to React.createElement(Foo) and correspond to a component
> defined or imported in your JavaScript file.
>
> We recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a
> component that starts with a lowercase letter, assign it to a
> capitalized variable before using it in JSX.